# Pygame-2.1.3.dev8 release not working with moviepy

Tags: python, pygame, moviepy, python-3.11

I tried installing pygame with pip install pygame --pre but that release(Pygame-2.1.3.dev8) of pygame seems to not be compatible with the moviepy library.

Does anyone know if there is some kind of workaround to get this to work?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\oscar\OneDrive\Skrivbord\Auto-tok\main.py", line 99, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\oscar\OneDrive\Skrivbord\Auto-tok\main.py", line 95, in main
    videostuff(reddit_json_blob)
  File "C:\Users\oscar\OneDrive\Skrivbord\Auto-tok\main.py", line 55, in videostuff
    final.show(2, interactive=True)
  File "C:\Users\oscar\OneDrive\Skrivbord\Auto-tok\venv\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\editor.py", line 118, in show
    raise ImportError("clip.show requires Pygame installed")
ImportError: clip.show requires Pygame installed
```

Comment: How confident are you that you actually have pygame installed in that venv? I checked the moviepy source, it just means it failed to import. I bet it would fail to import if you tried to import it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Pygame has not been ported to Python 3.11. I would downgrade to 3.10 and try that instead. There aren't many critical features added in 3.11 that I think you should be able to live without. I doubt you'll need `tomllib`, for instance.